# How to generate .exe from my python code like what other public python libraries do?

Tags: python-3.x, exe

I notice some of the public python libraries offer alternatives to run their main feature programs via .exe files in command line. For example, Cython has cython.exe and Pyinstaller has pyinstaller.exe to run in command line. I wonder if there is a standard way to do so, because I want to pack my own python package and then create an .exe file. I searched for quite a while but in vain.

Comment: I don't know if some configuration of setuptools might help...

Comment: Set up an entry point file might help build an extensible application?